# Laravel: TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, session, nginx, docker

I know about this exception but I can't fix this issue.

Things that you need to know:

- I'm using PHP 5.6 FPM, Nginx, MariaDB;
- I'm using Laravel 5.1.44;
- My app is working on server and have no issues;
- I'm in a new pc with docker. I lost my previous env and it was not installed using docker;
- I'm trying to use docker. I tested a lot of containers for a Lemp stack and none of them is working(for this project);
- Tested in home and at work(both using docker). Not working;
- Now I'm using https://github.com/LaraDock/laradock;
- I downloaded a login test project from github and it works.
- I don't know, but it looks like a session issue cause when I disable csrf  middleware, I try to login and the browser sends me back but it doesn't render an alert that uses session;
- But if I use "Session::put('test', 'bla')" and "Session::all()", 'test' is there.
- I got this error in all forms;
- I have csrf field in all forms;
- I tried to change "session.save_path" in "php.ini" and it also does not work.

And I don't know what to do. It's an issue that I can't fix :/

Any help? Something that I could try? Thank you!

EDIT #1

Right now I installed Nginx and PHP FPM using the same version that is in my docker containers and it's working. I installed them in my host machine without docker. 
It's not something that I like to do but it works and I can continue to dev my project.

This issue is not fixed yet cause I still can not run my project in a docker container :/

EDIT #2

Before post this question here I tested redis and it also was not working. 
Today, I read your replies and I tried with database and it works. 
Then I changed to file and it also works now(I did a chmod 777 in storage folder). But yesterday I did this(chmod storage) too, it's weird. And something strange that I notice is that when I reboot my pc, I always have to do a chmod in storage folder to my app works.

But now, I have this "Redirecting to zzzzz.com/aaa" when I have a redirect. Could be a space before a PHP open tag but is something that is not happening in my host machine(as I said in EDIT #1).

I'll try to fix this. Thank you guys!

Comment: i once had this problem switching from http to https, what i had to do was on the Config directory, on session.php i modified the domain and secure options. domain being the host name and secure to TRUE, don't know if that is your case

Comment: In my case, I'm in a development env without https..I have https on server and there it's working fine. What I can't understand is that in my last env for dev, it was working fine. Now I just installed docker, clone repo, up my env and everything is working but I'm having this issue with token.

Comment: uhmm maybe permission to write the session of token? check permissions for  /storage/framework/sessions

Comment: like @Carlos said its likely a permission thing, also check the driver you are using in your config. try changing to a database (to eliminate other options)

Comment: Question updated.